# What's a good way to move items in an list with AngularJS and ng-animate?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I want to be able to reorder a list, right now I have buttons on each item to move them up and down the list.  I want to use `ng-animate` to make the items move smoothly, but I can only find the `-move` animation, and that apparently only works on the top element of the two that are switching places.  I can't get it to look right.  Here's what I have so far: [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/k8kZd/2/)

```
.person-move {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
}

.person-move.person-move-active {
    height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I guess I'm not sure of the purpose of `-move`.  I'm swapping the places of two people, but it only seems to affect the top one.  I'd like it to look like they are being swapped.  in the sample fiddle there's a checkbox to create new objects instead of moving existing ones to fire -enter and -leave, maybe I could combine the two methods:

1. use `-move` for the top person (who used to be below), animating relative position upwards
2. use `-enter` for the bottom person by creating a new object, animating relative position

Is there an easier or better way to do this?

*Other thoughts*:
Something like jquery-ui's drag and drop would be nice, but I don't want to have to include it and find out if I can get it to work with AngularJS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I got it to work the way I wanted using the CSS next sibling selector, `+`: ([*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/kta95/1/))

```
.person-move {
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
}

.person-move.person-move-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    top: 0;
}

.person-move + div {
    /* cannot have transition on this element */
    /*transition: all 1s ease;*/
    position: relative;
    top: -26px;
}

.person-move.person-move-active + div {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

The key was to have the transition style *only* on the active class selectors.  The examples I've seen like on [yearofmoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html#animating-ng-repeat) have them on the base classes which I can't see any reason for since those are there solely to set up the initial condition for the animation I believe.  Chrome doesn't like it anyway and tries to animate to the initial condition when using the sibling selector.